# How do I fix the this rig to blend it's knees the right way?

Tags: rigging

i'am currently having a problem with my rig. It doesn't wanna seem to blend like a normal leg would. I noticed this problem after I added the Inverse Kinematics. Here are some pictures. 
[image: The leg wont bend the right way when i lift up the IK handle]

[image: When I move the main contral down it still bends the wrong way]

Answer (score 4):

When you add an Inverse Kinematic constraint to a bone, the Inverse Kinematic panel, in the Bone tab, allows you to lock the axes you don't wont the bone to rotate on.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a bone out in front of the knee and set it as the pole target for the IK constraint.

[image: ik settings]

The bones affected by IK will point towards the pole target as best they can.

[image: sample with pole]

Comment: Thank you all for helping me out, both sambler and Matt Ferndz's imput helped me out a ton. You guys are the best.