# Mesh moving in the opposite direction to bones

Tags: rigging

I'm very new to blender. I've meshed a basic structure and added some bones for the legs, but the mesh is moving in the wrong direction for one of the legs. See the video below:

https://gfycat.com/MagnificentThatLaughingthrush

Any idea how I can get the mesh for the right leg to move outwards?

[image]

Comment: It looks like an IK issue to me. Does [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/68323/2217) help?

Comment: I have taken a look at IK settings but couldnt seem to figure it out. In the video, the bones are moving as I want them to, its just the mesh which isn't following properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem follow this:

1. Select your mesh and apply the mirror modifier and delete the armature modifier
   [image]
2. Delete all vertex groups in your mesh[image]
3. Select your mesh then <kbd>Shift</kbd>
   and Right-Click select your armature then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and choose `parent with automatic weight` and it should work

[image]